# Can OpenLayers plugin be faster?

Tags: qgis, openlayers

Can the OpenLayers QGIS plugin be modified to have better map loading performance? I use only Google satellite/maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ideas that require programming skills. Basically: loading the map even if some tiles are still missing.

For a longer explanation, check the recent discussion on the mailing list: http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Openlayer-plugin-performance-ideas-td4974802.html